# How does trading work?

Tags: pokemon-go

During the last event (The one that spawned a ton of Ralts with increased shiny chance) I got multiple shiny Ralts. My friend didn't get any so I wanted to trade him one of mine. But when I tried it said that I didn't have enough stardust. It doesn't say how much more I need it just says I can't trade. How much stardust do I need to trade?

Then later I traded with another friend and we tried to trade again but it said I can only do one special trade per day. Is there another way to trade pokemon so we can do it multiple times in one day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special trades are unregistered, shiny or Legendary Pokemon.

The amount of stardust depends on your friendship level and what you are trading it can be between 100- 1,000,000 stardust.

You can find the exact value of the trade you want to do with a quick search.

For shiny Pokemon that is new:

- Good - 1,000,00
- Great - 800,000
- Ultra - 80,000
- Best - 40,000

The only time they have allowed multiply special trade in one day is if you are at a go fest.